# Can I use the GNOME Activities view for managing windows in Unity?

Tags: 12.04, unity, gnome

Is it possible to get the GNOME Shell Activities method for managing windows in Unity?

I would like to be able to move the mouse cursor to the top left corner of the screen to show all my windows on the workspace and close windows.

Answer (score 1):

you can configure it using *Ubuntu tweak*.in ubuntu tweak tool goto...tweaks-workspace and make the *top left* as **SHOW DESKTOP**   but you can't close windows when viewing all windows.[image]

Comment: okay :) but i dont have the workspace menu in ubuntu tweak

Comment: are you using ubuntu 2d?

Comment: yes :) i think i mabey now the answer now

Comment: But is it impossoibel to get a function so i can close the windowds 

btw. i am running unity 3d now

Comment: yes...i mentioned that problem with my answer...you can't close windows when using that effect.

Comment: @Prasad: you can, if you use CCSM to enable scale addons.

Comment: I alredy youse scale addons. 
but it is still not a option to close my windows when i use show workspaces

Comment: Thanks @RolandTaylor taylor I almost forgot that!!!....yes you can close them..use mouse middle click to close windows...when in SHOW WINDOWS mode..use mouse middle click to close it! simple